# sql内でIF文を２つ使いたい

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1),
              (SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1),
              Product.f_price
            )
```

上記のような、IFで、`(SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1)`と`Product.f_price`、算出される数値が100より下なら100,100以上なら、そのまま数値を出したいのですが

```
 IF(EXISTS(SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1),
        IF((SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1)<100),
              100,
              (SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1),
        IF(Product.f_price < 100),
              100,
              Product.f_price,
            )
```

上記のような形になると思いますが、どのような記述になりますか？
MySQLのバージョンは5.6です。

Comment: CASEを使えば１つのSELECTで書けると思いますよ。

Comment: IF,EXISTをCASEに埋め込むことはできますか？

Comment: `Product.price_h_id`がどこから来ているのか質問文だけでは不明ですけれども、JOINすることになるかもしれません。EXISTSはNOT EXISTSの使い方でなければ通常別の書き方があると思います。ちなみにIF(cond, true value, false value)はCASEと同じ働きをするので、CASEだから解決できるわけではなくて、SELECT IF(...), IF(...) でも書けるはず。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問を整理すると、こんな感じでしょうか。間違っていたらご指摘ください。

1. price_hテーブルにproductが存在すればpriceを出力、しないならProduct.f_priceを出力
2. この出力が<100なら100、そうでないなら、その値を出力

1についてはCOALESCEを使えば、NULLでない最初の値が出力されます。IFNULL()を使っても書けます。

```
SELECT COALESCE(price_h.price, Product.f_price) 
FROM price_h LEFT JOIN Product ON price_h.id = Product.price_h_id
```

2についてはpriceが<100なら100,それ以上ならpriceをそのまま出すには

```
SELECT  IF(price < 100, 100, price)
FROM price_h
```

組み合わせれば

```
SELECT IF(COALESCE(price_h.price, Product.f_price) < 100,
          100, 
          COALESCE(price_h.price, Product.f_price))
FROM price_h LEFT JOIN Product ON price_h.id = Product.price_h_id
```

Comment: 上記の回答の説明どうりです。自分の説明できていない部分もその通りです。
IF(EXISTS(SELECT price FROM price_h WHERE id = Product.price_h_id limit 1),

SELECT  IF(price_h < 100, 100, price_h),
SELECT  IF(price < 100, 100, price)
と記述してできました。